# WebSocket communication blocking the UI

Tags: javascript, multithreading, performance, asynchronous, websocket

I am currently working on a VNC Viewer using JavaScript. For the connection between my VNC Viewer and the server, I am using WebSocket communication.

It is all set and running, but I am currently suffering from big periods of time where the interface blocks and no action is possible for the user (a few seconds even).

The issue appears when a big amount of data is transferred from the server. In a test case, the image sent from the server was about 30MB. The data is also strongly split into small several blob messages (from 160B to 5KB per message) which make me receive around 10000 messages per screen refresh.

In this case, meanwhile the data is being collected, the main thread is not functional any longer.

My question is: why does WebSocket block my main thread? There are asynchronous calls that should be not blocking. Is there a way to avoid this block?

In the attached screenshot of the profile, it can be seen that 'other' is consuming almost all the busy time of my application.

[image]

Here it is the handling of the message:

```
p.socketReceivedMessage = function (message) {
    var that = this;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        _setBufferData(reader.result, that);
        that.onMessageRecived();
        if (that.queueingBytes) {
            if (that.bytesQueued >= that.byteToQueue) {
                that._resolver(_getBufferData(that.byteToQueue, that));
                that.queueingBytes = false;
            }
        }
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(message.data);
};
```

But even if I comment out the content of the function, the system still being slow.

I have read about WebWorker and the possibility to run code on a separate thread but I would like to understand why WebSocket is blocking my UI when it should be somehow handled by the browser on the background?

Comment: i think it's not the websocket but the way your browser handle the data you send / get.  That could be one case.
The second thing, is how many new data you get every seconds. If your file is split and send with 10 000 chunk per seconds, I think that's why your UI freeze

Comment: Thansk for the answer! Is there any way to recollect this data into bigger frames so the UI is not freeze? I have partial access to the proxy doing the translation from tcp to websocket but I would prefer to handle it better directly from the client side. I guess that WebWorker will be a solution to handle everything on the background but would like to hear if anyone has a different approach on mind.

Comment: I didn't try to work with websocket and big file recently so I don't know if there is a new way to handle big file.
But one good way to do it would be to use webworker. This way every thing will be handle in another 'thread' and shouldn't impact your UI.

Comment: @gre_gor Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm facing a similar issue with the UI janking when receiving messages from websockets.